# Insert button is not inserting my data inside the database; what is missing?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have the following, but the data isn't being inserted:

```
protected void InsertButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Program X = new Program();
    X.StudentName1 = NameTxt.Text;
    X.SudentAge1 = int.Parse(AgeTxt.Text);
    X.StudentID1 = int.Parse(IDTxt.Text);
    X.Insert();
}
```

This is my Insert method

```
// Insert Method 
public void Insert()
{
    SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection(DBC.Constructor);
    string Sql = "insert into Details (StudentID,StudentName,SudentAge) Values (@StudentID1,@StudentName1,@SudentAge1)";
    SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand(Sql, Connection);
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentID1", StudentID);
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentName1", StudentName);
    Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentAge1", SudentAge);


    try
    {
        Connection.Open();
        Command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Execute success");
        }

        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Execute is not success");
        }

    }
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error saving Student");
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {

            Connection.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And what is `X.Insert();` ? What **exactly** happens when you run this? Does it throw an exception? Or does it just not do anything? Where / how are you looking to check that no data was inserted? (a common error is misunderstanding file-based databases)

Comment: First set a break point in visual studio to find out exactly where the code is getting to. Are the variables set correctly?
Is insert even being called? If all that checks out can you print the code of the insert function?

Comment: it just doesnt do any thing at all , and i dont have any errors sir , please help me

Comment: What is the error you are getting when you running this code ?

Comment: No errors at all sir the error doesnt do any thing

Comment: please share some code from the Insert Method.

Comment: Sir i have just made a new quastion and its a little bit more clear than this one please sir go to my profile and see it if you can dear sir

Comment: I asked you a number of questions pertinent to your issue, and you have ignored them. I am asking them because they are **necessary** to answering your question. So: what are the answers? Without that, this is unanswerable.

Comment: Why did you do that? Why didn't you just EDIT THIS ONE?

Comment: ok i did edit it sir im ssorry but i just didnt sleep and i can barley open my eyes i need to know whats wrong before i go to my school

Comment: With the edit, my first thought is "you are writing to the console, from a UI app; a UI app ***doesn't have a console***. So: if you put a breakpoint on the various `catch` lines, and run it in the debugger: do you hit those breakpoints? i.e. is the issue simply that you're not showing the exception that happens?

Comment: YES sir the button doesnt respond at all

Comment: @user3192737 do you mean that a breakpoint on `Program X = new Program();` never gets hit? Did you actually hook the `InsertButton_Click` method to the button's `Click` event?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't intended as an answer; it is intended to show simplified, cleaner, and more robust coding of the same, to help you find the problem:

```
protected void InsertButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   try
   {    
        var X = new Program(); // this line is a really good place for a
                               // breakpoint (press F9)
        X.StudentName1 = NameTxt.Text;
        X.SudentAge1 = int.Parse(AgeTxt.Text);
        X.StudentID1 = int.Parse(IDTxt.Text);
        X.Insert();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        SomeMeaningfulAndWorkingExceptionDisplayMethod(ex);
    }
}

public void Insert()
{
    const string Sql = @"
    insert into Details (StudentID,StudentName,SudentAge)
    Values (@StudentID1,@StudentName1,@SudentAge1)";

    using(var conn = new SqlConnection(DBC.Constructor))
    using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(Sql, conn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("StudentID1", StudentID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("StudentName1", StudentName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("StudentAge1", SudentAge);
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this in your insert Method? If you are using ADO.net you have to execute the command you build up which it doesn't look like you did from what you posted in the comments.

```
            try
            {
                SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection(DBC.Constructor);
                string Sql = " Update Details Set Details = @StudentName1 , SudentAge1 = SudentAge1                            
                Where StudentID1 = @StudentID1";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Sql, Connection);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("StudentID1", StudentID); 
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("StudentName1", StudentName);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("SudentAge1", SudentAge);
                connection.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
```

Comment: no sir i did make an insert statment in another class and i did make parameters and every thing

Comment: SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection(DBC.Constructor);

            string Sql = " Update Details Set Details = @StudentName1 , SudentAge1 = SudentAge1 Where StudentID1 = @StudentID1";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Sql, Connection);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("StudentID1", StudentID);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("StudentName1", StudentName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("SudentAge1", SudentAge);

Comment: is the insert statement declared on your Program class? And if so please paste the code for the Insert implementation so that we may see it.

Comment: Paste the whole insert method from the start of the declaration and put it in your question.

Comment: That should use `ExecuteNonQuery`, not `ExecuteReader`...

Comment: Sir i have just made a new quastion and its a little bit more clear than this one please sir go to my profile and see it if you can dear sir

Comment: Good Call @MarcGravell :)

Comment: Sir i did edit my quastion

Answer (score 0):

try this code and check whether your database values matches this insert values

```
  protected void InsertButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{



    Insert(name.txt,convert.to.int16(AgeTxt.Text),convert.to.int16(IDTxt.Text));
}


// Insert Method 
 public void Insert(string name,int age,int studentid)
{
          SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection(DBC.Constructor);
        string Sql = "insert into Details (StudentID,StudentName,SudentAge) Values    (@StudentID1,@StudentName1,@SudentAge1)";
          SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand(Sql, Connection);
         Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentID1", studentid);
          Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentName1", name);
          Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentAge1", age);


     try
     {
    Connection.Open();
    Command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Execute success");
    }

    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Execute is not success");
    }

}
catch
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error saving Student");
}
finally
{
    try
    {

        Connection.Close();
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
 }
```